# Slurm inline sbatch command submission

Tags: bash, command-line, slurm, sbatch

with PBS scheduler is possible launch a batch command without script in this way:

`qsub -l select=1:ncpus=12:mem=112GB -l walltime=00:30:00 -- /usr/bin/bash -c "mpirun -np 12 sleep 10"`

Is it possible do it in Slurm with sbatch?

Answer (score 10):

Yes with the `--wrap` option:

```
sbatch ... --wrap "mpirun -np 12 sleep 10"
```

From the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html):

> --wrap= Sbatch will wrap the specified command string in a simple "sh" shell script, and submit that script to the slurm
>   controller. When --wrap is used, a script name and arguments may not
>   be specified on the command line; instead the sbatch-generated wrapper
>   script is used.